# parallel SELECT...FOR UPDATE causing mariaDB high CPU usage

Tags: php, mariadb

I am trying to test different ways to move 1M data from one table to another without locking the whole tables and then mark the rows as processed.
I have two scripts, one using a simple insert select (limitedLock.php) and another that can be run in parallel (parallel.php)
Both scripts use the same database fixtures
I running each script in CLI mode with this commands :

```
date && limitedLock.php && date
date & php parallel.php & php parallel.php & php parallel.php & wait && date
```

Surprisingly, both scripts are running as fast (18s each on my computer) but when running parallel.php, mariadb is using all the CPU (top command show 300% usage !!!).
I don't understand what cause parallel.php to use so much CPU and what can I do to prevent this ?

here is the code to reproduce the problem :

```
<?php
//fixture.php
$createFrom = <<<SQL
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS from_table(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `state` VARCHAR(10),
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    KEY state_idx (state)
)
SQL;

$createTo = <<<SQL
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS to_table(
    id INT,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
)
SQL;


$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=mariadb;dbname=some_db', 'root', 'root');

$conn->exec('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS from_table');
$conn->exec('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS to_table');
$conn->exec($createFrom);
$conn->exec($createTo);
$values = str_repeat("('to_process'),", 1_000_123);
$insert = 'INSERT INTO from_table (`state`) VALUES ' . rtrim($values, ',');
$conn->exec($insert);
```

limitedLock.php:

```
<?php

$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=mariadb;dbname=some_db', 'root', 'root');
$lastId = 0;
$limit = 1000;

do {
    $select = <<<SQL
SELECT id
FROM from_table
WHERE id > {$lastId}
AND state = 'to_process'
ORDER BY id
LIMIT {$limit}
SQL;
    $stmt = $conn->query($select);
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
    $ids = array_column($result, 'id');
    $lastId = end($ids);
    $inClause = implode(',', $ids);

    $insert = <<<SQL
INSERT INTO to_table(id)
SELECT id
FROM from_table
WHERE id IN ({$inClause})
SQL;

    $update = <<<SQL
UPDATE from_table
SET state = 'processed'
WHERE id IN ({$inClause})
SQL;

    $conn->beginTransaction();
    $conn->exec($insert);
    $conn->exec($update);
    $conn->commit();
} while (count($ids) === $limit);
```

parallel.php

```
<?php

$lockRows = <<<SQL
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ids_to_process
SELECT id
FROM from_table
WHERE state = 'to_process'
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 1000
FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
SQL;

$insert = <<<SQL
INSERT INTO to_table(id)
SELECT ft.id
FROM from_table ft
JOIN ids_to_process itp ON itp.id = ft.id
SQL;

$update = <<<SQL
UPDATE from_table ft
JOIN ids_to_process itp ON itp.id = ft.id 
SET state = 'processed'
SQL;

$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=mariadb;dbname=some_db', 'root', 'root');
$stmt = $conn->query('SELECT id FROM from_table order by id desc limit 1');
$lastId = (int) $stmt->fetch()['id'];

do {
    $conn->exec('SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED');
    try {
        $conn->beginTransaction();
        $conn->exec($lockRows);
        $conn->exec($insert);
        $conn->exec($update);
        $conn->exec('DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS ids_to_process');
        $conn->commit();
        //echo getmypid() . " - commited\n";
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $conn->rollBack();
        exit(getmypid() . PHP_EOL . $e->getMessage());
    }

    //if last id is in to_table then all rows have been transfered and the loop must stop
    $stmt = $conn->query("SELECT id FROM to_table WHERE id = {$lastId} limit 1");
    $result = $stmt->fetch();
} while (empty($result));
```

Comment: Your question seems to be a good example for the XY-Problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) - Maybe you should start with your table-structure and what you actually want to achieve?

Comment: I am doing benchmarking, nothing more that what I already wrote : I am trying to test different ways to move 1M data from one table to another without locking the whole tables. There is no underlaying problem.

Comment: What integer is `1_000_123`? Anyway, I don't quite understand how "parallel.php" can do the move asynchronous? My guess as to why your processor runs hot over "parallel.php" is that your temporary table doesn't have an index. That requires a lot of in-memory searching without any slower hardware holding the CPU back.

Comment: Why did you think this is a problem? It's parallel so multiple cores will work at the same time, isn't it?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware each parallel thread treats 1K rows per loop. The extra 123 is there to see how does the script behave when a chunk is less than 1K.
parallel.php is running asynchronous thanks to the sql clause "FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED". It allows each thread to read different rows avoiding deadlocks. You might be right beside the tempory table is really small (it only contains 1K rows) without index it can be a problem, thank you

Comment: @shingo you are right but if there is a way to save some resources I would be really interested to know it.